# Pass parameters into stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, procedure

can someone help me or point me to where I can find information on how to pass all the values of a column as parameters into a stored procedure? I need to run a stored procedure on all values in a column...

For example, column "Color" has the values black, gold, green, and blue. I want my stored procedure to take the values one at a time and run the procedure on them

Comment: In what RDBMS? To clarify, you want to run over every row in your table and pass a particular column to a stored procedure? Do you expect to execute the procedure _once_ with all column values simultaneously, or _once per row_ from the input table?

Comment: Hi - T-SQL in MS SQL Server. I want the procedure once per row from the input table. For example, column "Color" has the values black, gold, green, and blue. I want my stored procedure to take the values one at a time and run the procedure on them.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to execute procedure for each record in a column is using cursor approach. 
    DECLARE @color varchar(100)

```
DECLARE cc CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT color FROM Table
OPEN cc
FETCH NEXT FROM cc INTO @color
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN 

EXEC procedure @color

FETCH NEXT FROM cc INTO @color
END
CLOSE cc
DEALLOCATE cc
```

The best solution would be to use table valued parameters. This woould allow to create a procedure which accepts a temp table as a parameter. It would allow you to stick to set based approach and achieve the best performance.